# where did I go wrong with the quotes in this string?

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I inserted this whole string in this variable , but it is not working ... I am pretty sure it's a quote issue .. it's inside single quotes.. where did i go wrong ?

```
$new_image .='<td> <a href="#" onclick="return false;"><img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_select.gif" border="0" alt="Select" title=" Select " onclick="popupWindowSelectImg('./images_select.php?imgSize=thumb&inpt=products_image_sm_1&div=div_img_sm1&width=200&height=30','thumb','products_image_sm_1','div_img_sm1');"></a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighter clearly shows your issue which,  of course, is a quote:

```
onclick="popupWindowSelectImg('./images_select.php?
                            ^^^^^
                            HERE
```

You need to escape all of the single quotes in that string.

Comment: It saddens me to see how many people haven't discovered the wonder of syntax highlighting. Or the "preview" box.

Comment: @John , I actually did just that.. escaping right before I got your answer.. thanks anyways